# Jquery binding clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a lot of click events in jQuery **like** this:

```
$(".make").click(function() {
   make()
})
$(".go").click(function() {
   go()
})
$(".get").click(function() {
   get()
})
$(".set").click(function() {
   set()
})
```

I want to control these in one click event:

```
$(".make, .go, .do, .get, .set").click(function() {
     var func = $(this).attr('class');
     setTimeout(func, 0)
})
```

But this is not working, how can I control all click events like above method?

Comment: can you please post your HTML? There can me many reason for not working!

Comment: There is nothing to post HTML because selectors are just buttons.

Comment: create a fiddle for this

Comment: Can you confirm the separate click event handlers work?

Comment: i cant see anything wrong with your code! did you try consoling the func var?

Comment: Do `make`, `go`, `get` and `set` exist? Where does it get upto in terms of breakpoints? You have to be explicit about the way in which it's "not working".

Comment: Fyi, `do` is a reserved name, so you can't use it as a function name.

Comment: @balzafin do() is just an example.

Comment: @DeeMac all click events are exist and working. But when I use above method I'm getting `ReferenceError: funcName is not defined`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:-

```
$(".make, .go, .do, .get, .set").click(function() {
 var func = $(this).attr('class');
 setTimeout( window[func], 0)
})
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kx2ojpna/)

Comment: Thank you but this method is not working and not giving any error.

Comment: @Lazy how you define your functions?

Comment: `function make() { alert("test") }`

Comment: I noticed I had to put functions to outside of `$(document).ready)`, thanks.

Comment: or you could collect them in another object, if you don't want them to be global

Answer (score -5):

You cannot use strings as placeholders for a function.
Try it like this:

```
var myFunc = {
    a: function(){alert('a');},
    b: function(){alert('b');}
};
$('#a, #b').click(function(){
  myFunc[$(this).attr('id')]();
}
```

Well, okay techinically, you can use strings in a setTimeout, but the string contents will be evaluated, the javascript runtime will not go and look for a function which has the same name as your string, that is

```
setTimeout(function () {alert('A');}, 0);
// equals to this
setTimeout("alert('A')", 0);
// but 
function a(){ alert('A');}
setTimeout('a', 0)
// will fail
```

Comment: Technically, you can, and he is. Whether it's advised or not is a different issue. You haven't really answered his question.

Comment: you can, if you use the whole function content. you cannot define `function a(){}` and then do `setTimeout('a',0)`

Comment: See Mohit's answer. That is how you use strings as reference to a function.

Comment: That's just another way to go about it. But this only works if your functions are indeed global, and you have `window` available.